# Bootstrap 3 jCarousel trying to keep image centered as the browser gets wider

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jcarousel

I am working with some 1240px wide images that are being loaded into a jCarousel slider, and what happens is they look great when the browser width matches the image width, but when i widen the browser, the images expand not from the center, but from the top.

http://www.webwarephpdevelopment.com:8080/

I would like for the images to stay centered in the slider as I widen it.

Comment: Please post the relative code or create a JS.Fiddle. The url you posted is a 404.

Comment: ok...i fixed the url...sorry about that